# Is there a board for manager to check the progress of all test plans?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

When I open the dashboard, I can see the progress of test run which assigned to me. But as a test manager, I want to check the progress of all test plans which assigned to the testers. Now, I have to open each test plan to check the processing. So do TCMS have a similar function board for the manager?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking something I can't understand or asking about something which doesn't exist yet. So far only test runs have the notion of progress. Do you want to filter (how) TRs and see progress for each one of them or somehow filter test plans and see a cumulative progress aggregated across all TRs in the chosen TPs ?

Comment: I see. Yes, I want to see a cumulative progress aggregated across all TRs. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a cumulative information about TestRun execution progress check Telemetry -> Testing -> Execution trends. It provides the info you are looking for. From the latest version 8.0 there is also a progress bar showing you total number of tests + total number of statuses.

You can filter by product, version, build and particular test plan. You can also filter by timestamp. In the future (see menu option Telemetry -> More coming soon) there will also be possibility to group by weeks, not test runs.

If this doesn't provide what you need then you have to explain to us what is missing and how do you imagine it to look like. If you can provide a sketch that would be even better.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I need a dashboard like below:/
Tester  Progress  TestRunName/
John processbar 17%  TestRun A/
John processbar 100%  TestRun B/
Peter processbar 0%  TestRun C/
Antonov processbar 97%  TestRun D/ 
I can not add a image in the comment. You can wrap at slash in above. sorry for a bad look.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest comment it looks like you are looking for what we call:
Individual or team performance telemetry, see 
https://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2019/03/03/legacy-reports-become-telemetry/

At the time of writing this is still not implemented, however it is on our backlog to do so. All of the mentioned reports in the blog post above will be implemented as part of the first batch of testing telemetry.